# Two Dimensional Database Design -SQL or JSON

Tags: json, database, sqlite, rolap

I need a database design advice. I am currenty using SQLite ( or i can switch to any other database for those tables)  I have  A,B,C,D  columns with  rows  from 24 to 1008 .   X represents whether the column empty or not.

my first idea->  I can do Table A,B,C,D  with 24 to 1008   (which seems dumb)

second idea -> something like table X (which has id(FK) to another table where I will be getting report ID) which has  24 to 1008 and values will be  A,B,C  or D  so in this case an example query is :  SELECT A from table X JOIN table_report ON table.report.id=X.id where table_report.id=3;

so  with 4 queries I will be getting values for  A,B,C and D  however I am confused  a lot now

Efficiency is not a big deal atm however I don't want to design a dumb thing.  I will be filling HTML tables with those data ( Express+ejs)

I am open for any advice

https://i.hizliresim.com/PO7PV5.png

Comment: Please show us what the data looks like.  Typically 4 columns versus 4 tables is not a decision choice you would be facing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   there is no data actually. there are tickboxes for each column.  It is either checked or not.  https://i.hizliresim.com/EyO5jB.png

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give a best design with the limited info you've provided. But it's likely you need to study some of the principles of RDB design.

The natural way of representing what you show in the image would be as a table of unique pairs, where each pair denotes one entry with an X:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  hour INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  tag TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Note I'm guessing a name of "hour" for the numerical horizontal axis and "tag" for the vertical A - D axis, since you didn't mention what these values actually are.

You'd enforce the additional data constraints with triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_schedule_insert BEFORE INSERT ON schedule
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN NEW.hour NOT IN (24, 48, ...) OR NEW.tag NOT IN ("A", "B", "C", "D")
    THEN RAISE (ABORT 'Bad pair')
  END;
END;
```

The maximum number of entries in the table would be 4 * 42 = 164. You'd check whether a given entry has an X with:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE hour = ? AND tag = ?;
```

This returns 1 or 0 results for X or no X respectively.

Of course you can learn all the tags with an X for a given hour with a single query:

```
SELECT tag FROM schedule WHERE hour = ?;
```

Comment: well actually there is no data, imagine tickboxes for each  A,B,C,D and their related hours.  Data:  whether they are ticked or not

Comment: I never said there was any data other than presence or absence of X. @emredeli

Comment: @emredeli If you're talking about my mention of "data constraint", that refers to allowing the database to accept _only valid pairs_.  I.e. you don't want it to accept a pair of ("E", 99) because those aren't on the axes.

Comment: I understand what do you mean, my plan is to read   req.body with values  A1, A2  (up to 42)  and  D1,D2  so on.    afterwards i need to record those values into database

Comment: I mean it is like whether A24 is ticked or not